# Slider display only current active

Tags: jquery

[image]

> (I put this **image** so that I can elaborate my question)

I have this slider this is my **script**

```
var q = jQuery(".slides .flex-active-slide");
var e = jQuery(q).next("li").find("img").attr("src");
var y = jQuery(q).last().find("img").attr("src");

if(jQuery(q).first()){
  jQuery(".prev-thumb").css({"background-image":"url(" + y + ")"});
}else{
  jQuery(".prev-thumb").css({"background-image":"url(" + e + ")"}); 
}
```

and this is the **HTML**

```
<div class="project-slides">
    <ul class="slides">
        <li class="flex-active-slide"><img src="1"></li>
        <li class=""><img src="2"></li>
        <li class=""><img src="3"></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="flex-direction-nav">
        <li class="prev-click">
            <a class="flex-prev" href="#">Previous</a>
            <div class="prev-thumb same-thumb"></div>
        </li>
        <li class="next-click">
            <a class="flex-next" href="#">Next</a>
            <div class="next-thumb same-thumb"></div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

My question is why it display the current active not the previous image?

Comment: what is "current active"

Comment: the class with **flex-active-slide**  @SenthilNatarajan